# Use script from inside an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to assign a key to each cell of a user-generated table with unknown amounts of columns and rows:

e.g., HTML

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <select class="colheaders">
        <option value="firstname"> first name</option>
        <option value="familyname"> Family name</option>
       </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <select class="colheaders">
       <option value="firstname"> first name</option>
       <option value="familyname"> Family name</option>
      </select>    
     </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
   </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Jones</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of this

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function(row, tr) {
    TableData[row] = {
        "col1": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 
        "col2": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(), 
        "col3": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
    }
});
```

"col1" would be the selected option from the same row. Once Posted via AJAX I would be able to return a key->value array.

e.g.,

```
{
 "first name" : "bob",
 "family name" : "smith"
}
{
 "first name" : "John",
 "family name" : "Jones"
}
```

I currently have:

```
var TableData = new Array();
var colheaders = new Array();
var namerows = new Array();

$('.colheaders option:selected').each(function() {
    colheaders.push($(this).val());
});

var i;
for (i = 0; i < colheaders.length; i++) { 
    namerows.push('"' + colheaders[i]  + '" : $(tr).find("td:eq(' + i + ')").text()');
}   

$('#mytable tr').each(function(row, tr) {
    TableData[row] = namerows 
});
```

However this produces the script and not the cell.

```
"[[\"\\\"first name\\\" : $(tr).find(\\\"td:eq(0)\\\").text()\\n\",\"\\\family name"\\\" : $(tr).find(\\\"td:eq(1)\\\").text()\\n\",\"\\\"\\\" : $(tr).find(\\\"td:eq(2)\\\").text()\\n\"],
```

etc..

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, you are really overcomplicating it. So what is expected behaviour? Provide MCVE it should be more clear

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear. The first example is what I would like to produce but instead of col1, col2 etc.. replace col-x with values from drop down menus. Additionally the number of columns can vary.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to complicate things unnecessarily.`eval` is never a recommended option. Try this [**link**](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) to read more about it.

The logic is simple enough. The count of the selected options (lets call it **n** ) in `.colheaders` is the number of columns we have. So what you can do is that, inside the `each` function, make a loop which counts till **n** and fetches the column data of each `td`. Then at the end of the loop, you'll have the object which holds the data of the table row columns.

Try something like this.

```
var TableData = new Array();
var temp = {};
var selected = $('option:selected').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
var i;
var tableRows = $('#mytable tr');
tableRows.each(function(row, tr) {
    for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        temp = {};
        temp['col' + (i + 1)] = tableRows.children('td').eq( selected[i] ).text();
    }
    TableData[row] = temp;
});
```

Comment: Would have perhaps been a nicer comment to at least explain why eval isn't a recommended option - I'm not an expert I was just trying to help when no-one else had

Comment: @aspiring_programmer I'll try to make write an explanation.

Comment: this is a lot prettier however produces the same error. (I've updated the question with the example)

Comment: @MF_it I've made a change, can you check?

Comment: As i understand it, this is what OP is expecting

Answer (score 1):

You could map table rows and get relevant TDs text using:

```
var TableData = $('table tr').map(function(i, tr) {
    var row = {};
    $(tr).children('td').each(function(z, td) {
        return row['col' + z] = td.innerHTML;
    });
    return row;
}).get();
```

See if it fits your expected behaviour:

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: I think there is a dependency to the number of selected options `$('.colheaders option:selected')` in the OP. May be he doesn't want to get   all the columns. Didn't make much sense.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Oh ya, i missed it. That's why a MCVE in question would be really more helpful... :)

Comment: Thats correct Rejith, By replacing the col-'x' with the selected .colheaders I can assign a value to the cel's html

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff and thanks for the link. I have read it although I'm still terrible at making myself clear. :(

Comment: @MF_it You are quite clear, more than your code... :) But providing a simple example in question itself would make it easier to catch exactly what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but if you had a string which contained a function i.e.

```
var hi = "function hi() {alert('hi');}"
```

Use

```
eval(hi);
```

This will 'load in' the function and then you can call it using

```
hi();
```

I would make the whole function:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function(row, tr) {
TableData[row] = {
    "col1": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 
    "col2": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(), 
    "col3": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
}
});
```

^ a single string and then use this. So when you are generating the logic for namerows wrap that in a bigger string containing the outer function.

i.e.

```
var myFunc = "$('#mytable tr').each(function(row, tr) { TableData[row] = " + namerows + "});"

eval(myFunc);
myFunc();
```

Comment: Thank you, that still doesn't seem to work. When I post TableData[row] via ajax I see the script not the values

Comment: I slightly edited my answer - does that still not work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get feeling that the problem maybe is how I'm pushing the string into namerows?